# Modular Design (Separate Prototypes from Logic)

Tags: createjs

I am just starting using [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/CreateJS). It is easy enough to learn that I was able to quickly grasp its concepts.

I just included one JS file to contain all my logic and data structures. At first, it was serviceable. But over time, I got to the point where I have so many classes/prototypes in the JS file that I want to separate them from the logic inside that same file.

I don't think Javascript can share classes/prototypes between JS files. Is there a way to split this into manageable chunks? For example, I could put all my classes/prototypes in one file and all my logic into another. Or I can put a class/prototype in its own class.

I have heard good things about using [Node.j](http://nodejs.org/)s and [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) but I would prefer to use Javascript without using it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can share classes and prototypes from files in terms of once a class is loaded into the global scope, any subsequently loaded file will be able to access that class.

Managing dependancies manually like this can be hugely time consuming as you'll have to manually ensure that all of your files are loaded in the order that they are needed. You will also end up cluttering the global scope, which is generally considered a bad practise.

I know you have stated not using RequireJS, but it really does answer both of these problems. What need is a way to load scoped modules from other files, and this is exactly what require will do. It is not a huge learning curve and definitely worth the time investment.

Once you have got your head around AMD and requirejs, you can use tools like Rjs, which will concatinate and minify your code for you at build time, so your end users don't suffer the download overhead of many JS files.

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/) is a great start guide for requirejs.